# Advice on SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently working on a project which requires me to compare data from two table using sql. Basically, what it does is to check for any unauthorised room usage that was not booked. One example would be if a room was booked from 9 am to 11am, anything after it will be considered unauthorised. A sensor data will display data whether there's anyone in the room. 0 represent empty while 1 represent 1.

This is my SQL query:

```
select 
    cd.ROOMID,
    cd.DAY,
    cd.CLASSSTARTDATE1,
    cd.CLASSENDDATE1,
    count(sensorD.Timestamp) as Unauthorised_Visit
from 
    classroomData cd
inner join 
    sensorData sensorD on cast(sensorD.Timestamp as date) = cast(cd.CLASSENDDATE1 as date)
where 
    sensorD.[Occupied Status ] = '1' 
    and cast(sensorD.Timestamp as time) not between cast(cd.CLASSSTARTDATE1 as time) and cast(cd.CLASSENDDATE1 as time)
group by 
    cd.ROOMID, cd.DAY, cd.CLASSENDDATE1, cd.CLASSSTARTDATE1
```

The problem that I am facing now is in one day, a room can be booked at any time of the day. For example Room A is booked from 9am-11pm and 11am-1pm. Anytime not between 9-11 and 11-1 is considered unauthorised.

**Result Data**

[image]

**sample data**
[image]

The problem for the above code is that it will count any data that is not between 9am - 11am and will count together with 11am to 1pm when
I’ve specify not to count any data that has been booked. Any advice on how I can fix this?

This is the link to the sample sql database in sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3ea65/2

Comment: Please share sample data for more clarity

Comment: @codeLover I’ve edited the above post

Comment: I don't think you've correlated sensor and room IDs.

Comment: So that whole sensorData table is just for 1 roomId?

Comment: @LukStorms yes.. I’m currently focusing on one first

Comment: can you share a sample data set in sqlfiddle?

Comment: @theDbGuy http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3ea65/2

Comment: How difficult is it to click inside the result pane, hit ctrl a and ctrl + shift +C to copy the data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you simply wanting to join sensor data between room authorized periods and wanting to see difference? Simple left join will do the trick. I make common table expression cte1 to represent the booked time periods and populate it with one entry. Second CTE is sensor data with two entries.

Actual query is joining sensor data with booked data with left join, nulls show that sensor data happened when there was no booking.

```
;with cte1 as (
    select '2018-01-01 10:00' as s, '2018-01-01 12:00' as e
),
cte2 as (
    select '2018-01-01 11:00' as occup
    union all
    select '2018-01-01 13:00' as occup
)
select 
    case when cte1.s is null then 'Unauthorized' else 'Authorized' end as authorized,
    * 
from cte2
left outer join cte1 on cte2.occup between cte1.s and cte1.e
```

Result:

[image]

**Fitting the same Query with your fiddle:**

```
select 
    case when cd.ROOMID is null then 'Unauthorized' else 'Authorized'end as Authorized,
    cd.ROOMID,
    cd.[DAY],
    cd.CLASSSTARTDATE1,
    cd.CLASSENDDATE1,
    COUNT(sd.Timestamp) as Unauthorised_Visit,
    cast(sd.[Timestamp] as date) as dt
from 
    sensorData sd
    left join classroomData cd on sd.[Timestamp] between cd.CLASSSTARTDATE1 and cd.CLASSENDDATE1
where 
    sd.[Occupied Status] = 1
group by 
    cd.ROOMID, cd.[DAY], cd.CLASSENDDATE1, cd.CLASSSTARTDATE1, cast(sd.Timestamp as date)
```

This results as:
[image]

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3ea65/2 -- This is the link to the sample data

Comment: I used exactly the same query idea I presented to fit yours in fiddle. Usually I leave this work for the question author, but for some reason I fitted it this time.

Comment: Thank you so much. Ok, let say I want it formatted to unauthorized instead of authorized, do I change it to right join or not between?

Comment: Query selects both authorized and unauthorized so you can choose to filter the results you dont want. WHERE cd.ROOMID IS NULL and you will only get the unauthorized resultset.

Comment: Ok. Sorry, what I meant was I want to know which date has how many unauthorized visit, therefore I can use that data for other security purpose.

Comment: Add "cast(sd.[Timestamp] as date) as dt" to select list and "cast(sd.Timestamp as date) " to group by list.